# Simulate CSS Jquery Preloader

Tags: jquery, css, preloader

I'd like to test a css preloader animation, but because my content loads pretty fast already it's hard to see my css animation in action. The preloader is shown while content is being loaded, then it's hidden once the content loads.

I'm wondering if there's a way to simulate my preloader for a slow internet connect or some other way just so I can see it.

Below is the current jquery I'm using

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

 $("#loader").css({'display' : 'block'});


 $("#loader").animate({'top' : '25%',opacity: 0.55,});


 if($( "#content" ).load){




  $("#loader").css({'display' : 'none'});

  $("#content").css({'display' : 'block'});
  alert('page has loaded')
  $("#content").animate({opacity: 1},6000);


}
```

Comment: in chrome, you can open the developer tools, go to Emulation, and at the top of the window under Network set the throttling to simulate a slow network.

Comment: you could also just comment out your if($("content").load)){} then you will see your preloader run continually.